# Convert BSplineFunction into two Interpolating Functions

Tags: interpolation, parametric-functions, conversion, splines

Is there a way to decompose a `BSplineFunction` output into two functions `x[t]`, `y[t]` parametrizing the curve `BSplineFunction[{{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}, ...}][t]` in a form which allows easy calculation of derivatives of arbitrary order of `x[t]` and `y[t]` and of composite functions which use `x[t]` or `y[t]` like

```
f[t] = y''[t]/Sqrt[x'[t]^2+y'[t]^2]
f''[0.5]
```

etc. ?

Edit: I would also like to do this avoiding `SetDelayed` as much as it's possible.

Comment: An implementation by Gianluca Gorni: https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2448389

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When manipulating B-splines in this manner, it is often convenient to fall back on the definitions. Luckily, since *Mathematica* supplies the function `BSplineBasis[]`, using the definitions are easy:

```
pts = {{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {2, -1}, {3, 0}, {4, -2}, {5, 1}};

n = 3; (* B-spline degree *)
m = Length[pts];
(* clamped uniform knots for B-spline *)
knots = {ConstantArray[0, n + 1], Range[m - n - 1]/(m - n), ConstantArray[1, n + 1]}
        // Flatten;

{xu, yu} = Transpose[pts];
bs = BSplineFunction[pts, SplineDegree -> n];

(* B-spline component functions *)
f[t_] = xu.Table[BSplineBasis[{n, knots}, i - 1, t], {i, Length[pts]}];
g[t_] = yu.Table[BSplineBasis[{n, knots}, i - 1, t], {i, Length[pts]}];
```

Compare:

```
{ParametricPlot[bs[t], {t, 0, 1}, Axes -> None, Frame -> True,
                Epilog -> {Directive[AbsolutePointSize[5], Red], Point[pts]}], 
 ParametricPlot[{f[t], g[t]}, {t, 0, 1}, Axes -> None, Frame -> True,
                Epilog -> {Directive[AbsolutePointSize[5], Red], Point[pts]}]}
```

[image: Spot the difference!]

One can now plot the component functions as needed:

```
Plot[{f[t], g[t]}, {t, 0, 1}, Axes -> None, Frame -> True]
```

[image: B-spline components]

or use derivatives:

```
With[{t = 1/3}, g''[t]/Sqrt[f'[t]^2 + g'[t]^2]]
   48/Sqrt[41]
```

Comment: This is great, thank you so much!

Answer (score 5):

What about trying something like the following!

```
pts = {{1, 1}, {2, 3}, {3, -1}, {4, 1}, {5, 0}};
f = BSplineFunction[pts];
x[t_?NumericQ] := Module[{val}, val = f[t]; First@val];
y[t_?NumericQ] := Module[{val}, val = f[t]; Last@val];
```

Check it!

```
Plot[{x[t], y[t]}, {t, 0, 1}, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

Now the value you are looking for.

```
nf[t_?NumericQ] := y''[t]/Sqrt[x'[t]^2 + y'[t]^2];
nf''[0.5]
```

> -758.244

BR

Comment: Wow, that's a simple and awesome idea! SetDelayed did half of the job, but Module is obviously the winner. Thanks!

Comment: Though is there a way to do this without SetDelayed? I intend to use these functions in NDSolve inside Manipulate, thus SetDelayed is not welcome. x[t] by its nature is a known value, so why does it need to be SetDelayed?