# Parametric differentiable interpolation of a 2D data set

Tags: interpolation, splines

I have a set of data

```
table = Reverse[{
   {0, -947}, {-212, -947}, {-424, -950}, {-635, -963}, {-845, -995}, {-1051, -1044},
   {-1248, -1119}, {-1432, -1224}, {-1591,-1365}, {-1715, -1537}, {-1796, -1732}, 
   {-1828, -1942}, {-1810,-2153}, {-1755, -2357}, {-1668, -2551}, {-1556, -2730}, 
   {-1423,-2895}, {-1278, -3050}, {-1126, -3197}, {-973, -3343}, {-803,-3506}
}];
```

which I need to interpolate with a parametric curve. Endpoints and tangent vectors at them are critical. Trying independent polynomial fits for X and Y leads to a wavy curve which is unacceptable. `BSplineFunction` of degree around 3 leads to a very good-looking curve:

```
interp = BSplineFunction[table, SplineDegree -> 3];    
Show[ListPlot[table], ParametricPlot[interp[t], {t, 0, 1}], AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image]

but has a discontinuous derivative (btw: why? help promises that it should be a `BSplineFunction` of one lesser degree but it's a scary jump-step function if you plot it):

```
x1[t_?NumericQ] := Module[{val}, val = interp[t]; First@val]
y1[t_?NumericQ] := Module[{val}, val = interp[t]; Last@val]    
Plot[Norm[{x1'[t], y1'[t]}], {t, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

I then intend to use these functions in `NDSolve`, `NIntegrate` etc., therefore behaviour like above is too bad.
What parametric interpolation is better in this case?

Comment: What are `x1` and `y1`?

Comment: @VLC check the `x` and `y` in http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19229/convert-bsplinefunction-into-two-interpolating-functions

Comment: @PlatoManiac Ah, ok.

Comment: By extracting the values from the `BSplineFunction` and *then* differentiating, you are taking a finite difference derivative sampled at whatever points `Plot` feels like using. Try e.g. `Plot[Norm[interp'[t]], {t, 0, 1}]`, which I think you will find much better.

Comment: You may want to look at this method http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/33262/1364 It works for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Borrowing the `parametrizeCurve[]` routine from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/11659) (it's amazing what searching can do...), you can do this:

```
tvals = parametrizeCurve[table];
{ft, gt} = Interpolation[Transpose[{tvals, #}], Method -> "Spline"] & /@ Transpose[table];

ParametricPlot[{ft[u], gt[u]}, {u, 0, 1}, Axes -> None, Frame -> True,
               Epilog -> {AbsolutePointSize[4], Magenta, Point /@ table}]
```

[image: curve and points]

Verify the $C^2$ continuity:

```
{Plot[{ft'[u], gt'[u]}, {u, 0, 1}], Plot[{ft''[u], gt''[u]}, {u, 0, 1}]} // GraphicsRow
```

[image: derivative plots]

Comment: There turns out to be some substantial wavering at the lower end, so I had to come up with some crazy `Fit` with basis `{1,t,t^2,...,t^6,Exp[0.05 t],Cos[t]}` which magically led to incredibly smooth curve with constant-signed curvature.

Comment: All this is so important because of its architectural nature.

Answer (score 2):

(1) I get a reasonable result interpolating separately.

(2) I don't think your derivatives are doing what you expect.

```
x1 = Interpolation[table[[All, 1]]];
y1 = Interpolation[table[[All, 2]]];

Show[ListPlot[table], ParametricPlot[{x1[t], y1[t]}, {t, 1, 21}], 
 AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image]

Here are those derivatives.

```
Plot[{x1'[t], y1'[t]}, {t, 0, 21}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

If you raise the InterpolationOrder then those derivative curves get smoother.

Comment: Problem with `Interpolation` is that as soon as no points are close to each other, everything seems fine. But if data is not equidistant like this, the curve breaks between close points - something that doesn't happen with `BezierFunction` for example (though it's not an interpolation at all).