# Finding intersections of two parametric curves

Tags: equation-solving, interpolation, parametric-functions

I am dealing with the root finding of two parametric data curves (data below).

I have already checked [Parametric Interpolation of 2D data](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/47332/parametric-interpolation-of-2d-data), which I found useful for plotting, though it is not adequate for interpolating the data and consequently, for finding the point/s where both curves cross.

```
dat=# {1,10}&/@SortBy[im,-#[[1]]&];
a=First@dat;
b=Rest@dat;
pathim={1,.1} #&/@First@Last@Reap@Do[b=DeleteCases[b,a=Sow@Nearest[b,a][[1]],1];,{Length@b}];
dat=# {1,10}&/@SortBy[re,-#[[1]]&];
a=First@dat;
b=Rest@dat;
pathre={1,.1} #&/@First@Last@Reap@Do[b=DeleteCases[b,a=Sow@Nearest[b,a][[1]],1];,{Length@b}];
Graphics[Line@{pathre,pathim},AspectRatio->1,Frame->True]
```

[image: Crossing of parametric curves]

Consider that if you perform a parametric interpolation, you would still have the problem that both curves will have different parameters $t$ and $t'$.

Any help will be welcome. Thanks in advance,

Francisco

```
im={{0.0531041079509168`,0.4537856055185257`},{0.05466627362026595`,0.4363323129985824`},{0.055371695336473604`,0.47123889803846897`},{0.0587862063093332`,0.4188790204786391`},{0.05966729343396994`,0.4886921905584123`},{0.06002132511085396`,0.415948661223835`},{0.06002132511085396`,0.4896587722299967`},{0.06575305305020286`,0.4014257279586958`},{0.06620599426144534`,0.5061454830783556`},{0.07002487929599628`,0.3948582697541205`},{0.07002487929599628`,0.5135624010553028`},{0.07512591694116288`,0.5235987755982988`},{0.07616913318690677`,0.3839724354387525`},{0.08002843348113861`,0.37928209464467316`},{0.08002843348113861`,0.5333666581380405`},{0.08446817154140783`,0.5410520681182421`},{0.09003198766628094`,0.36758426429054275`},{0.09003198766628094`,0.5502658471113652`},{0.09086816581576561`,0.3665191429188092`},{0.09506524408809112`,0.5585053606381855`},{0.10003554185142327`,0.3585188972184474`},{0.10003554185142327`,0.5668389658408651`},{0.10599987363255793`,0.5759586531581288`},{0.11003909603656559`,0.3499821309207754`},{0.11003909603656559`,0.5822588977132048`},{0.11118556664133165`,0.3490658503988659`},{0.11751340259454512`,0.5934119456780721`},{0.12004265022170792`,0.344202114592412`},{0.12004265022170792`,0.5973515337967324`},{0.12869769426292388`,0.6108652381980153`},{0.13004620440685025`,0.33895717609139303`},{0.13004620440685025`,0.6131207072459866`},{0.13943871850933623`,0.6283185307179586`},{0.14004975859199256`,0.3337693543200807`},{0.14004975859199256`,0.6293735517037298`},{0.1448928765578632`,0.33161255787892263`},{0.15001734189017396`,0.6457718232379019`},{0.1500533127771349`,0.3299538513479695`},{0.1500533127771349`,0.6458374688532782`},{0.16005686696227722`,0.32724984607051905`},{0.16005686696227722`,0.663160407666875`},{0.1600947333741542`,0.6632251157578453`},{0.16939105761415585`,0.6806784082777885`},{0.17006042114741954`,0.32510426347930604`},{0.17006042114741954`,0.6820027152855632`},{0.17834315993959135`,0.6981317007977318`},{0.18006397533256188`,0.323456717685147`},{0.18006397533256188`,0.7020915043821209`},{0.18659140121444864`,0.7155849933176751`},{0.1900675295177042`,0.3224938152915452`},{0.1900675295177042`,0.7234506689272742`},{0.19432724424416561`,0.7330382858376184`},{0.20007108370284654`,0.32194010589163236`},{0.20007108370284654`,0.7473057900969771`},{0.20140343554157758`,0.7504915783575618`},{0.20824586759352762`,0.767944870877505`},{0.21007463788798886`,0.32198227941312596`},{0.21007463788798886`,0.7735544586917432`},{0.21440848678980026`,0.7853981633974483`},{0.22007819207313117`,0.32268480961476603`},{0.23008174625827352`,0.323717711816065`},{0.24008530044341583`,0.32536509061435503`},{0.2500888546285582`,0.32760449250820817`},{0.2600924088137005`,0.33028549462451157`},{0.26430223561363364`,0.33161255787892263`},{0.2700959629988428`,0.3339970032425843`},{0.2800995171839851`,0.33833635585161864`},{0.29010307136912744`,0.3431145125802778`},{0.3001066255542698`,0.348219551120407`},{0.3016794563236875`,0.3490658503988659`},{0.31011017973941213`,0.35487194552795387`},{0.32011373392455444`,0.36175350208401263`},{0.32674322227218133`,0.3665191429188092`},{0.33011728810969676`,0.3694992086937793`},{0.3401208422948391`,0.3779490778028813`},{0.34724156791654076`,0.3839724354387525`},{0.35012439647998145`,0.3869800216501857`},{0.36012795066512376`,0.397301449763025`},{0.3642757416734221`,0.4014257279586958`},{0.3701315048502661`,0.40818604597717256`},{0.3798968075860652`,0.4188790204786391`},{0.3801350590354084`,0.4191811250284763`},{0.3901386132205507`,0.4316677521878405`},{0.39414905060506983`,0.4363323129985824`},{0.4001421674056931`,0.44396444613816133`},{0.4080491550187325`,0.4537856055185257`},{0.4101457215908354`,0.45676212790254306`},{0.4201492757759777`,0.4696249603539099`},{0.42149486869254693`,0.47123889803846897`},{0.43015282996112003`,0.48258796657484376`},{0.4350833036679111`,0.4886921905584123`},{0.44015638414626235`,0.4954819929471901`},{0.4487072833146444`,0.5061454830783556`},{0.45015993833140466`,0.508055663432461`},{0.46016349251654703`,0.5202514638628473`},{0.46307521883939134`,0.5235987755982988`},{0.47016704670168935`,0.5322780570272747`},{0.477914190905029`,0.5410520681182421`},{0.48017060088683167`,0.5437317838666962`},{0.490174155071974`,0.5544902541741973`},{0.4941879210211103`,0.5585053606381855`},{0.5001777092571164`,0.5648273949103115`},{0.5101812634422587`,0.5748053095034658`},{0.5114599742898591`,0.5759586531581288`},{0.520184817627401`,0.5841495962231561`},{0.5301883718125433`,0.5931600434577045`},{0.5304986382227892`,0.5934119456780721`},{0.5401919259976856`,0.6015014405876375`},{0.5501954801828279`,0.6092182031363506`},{0.5525479998123303`,0.6108652381980153`},{0.5601990343679702`,0.6165152214659495`},{0.5702025885531126`,0.6233328283352525`},{0.5781515740734545`,0.6283185307179586`},{0.5802061427382549`,0.6296561108077645`},{0.5902096969233973`,0.6355223762629595`},{0.6002132511085396`,0.6408151697372594`},{0.6102168052936819`,0.6457035790124366`},{0.6103667848233747`,0.6457718232379019`},{0.6202203594788243`,0.6504250134981324`},{0.6302239136639666`,0.6543542727813271`},{0.6402274678491089`,0.6577018258959079`},{0.6502310220342512`,0.6608382810360297`},{0.65893148745905`,0.6632251157578453`},{0.6602345762193935`,0.6636086146790213`},{0.6702381304045358`,0.6660358970840763`},{0.6802416845896782`,0.6679454676068672`},{0.6902452387748205`,0.6692245391152624`}};re={{0.3766619334176538`,0.6283185307179586`},{0.3774833614565732`,0.6457718232379019`},{0.37836289304330173`,0.5934119456780721`},{0.3794436621915606`,0.6632251157578453`},{0.3800679818708404`,0.5844653112819048`},{0.3800679818708404`,0.667375571838723`},{0.3818120099506517`,0.5759586531581288`},{0.38212616179315456`,0.6806784082777885`},{0.38540217552140743`,0.6981317007977318`},{0.3882567605401741`,0.5585053606381855`},{0.38938774795241116`,0.7155849933176751`},{0.39006977086744143`,0.5551487025539988`},{0.39006977086744143`,0.7184208526690175`},{0.39384490677070083`,0.7330382858376184`},{0.3983398475296372`,0.5410520681182421`},{0.3990895276046064`,0.7504915783575618`},{0.4000715598640425`,0.5390451811857366`},{0.4000715598640425`,0.7536360014898048`},{0.40490154189174227`,0.767944870877505`},{0.4100733488606436`,0.5288508576882919`},{0.4100733488606436`,0.7829547200266151`},{0.4109671363156394`,0.7853981633974483`},{0.41590869326136504`,0.5235987755982988`},{0.42007513785724465`,0.5208888749031353`},{0.4300769268538457`,0.5152293488576334`},{0.4400787158504468`,0.5105095807330549`},{0.45008050484704787`,0.5063401987861282`},{0.45064664649866976`,0.5061454830783556`},{0.4600822938436489`,0.5036814650968815`},{0.47008408284024994`,0.5014626165676501`},{0.48008587183685103`,0.4996348462112899`},{0.4900876608334521`,0.4982219621388478`},{0.5000894498300532`,0.49707951766544517`},{0.5100912388266542`,0.4964390647155012`},{0.5200930278232553`,0.4958486047744673`},{0.5300948168198564`,0.49545500725491304`},{0.5400966058164574`,0.49521155256588884`},{0.5500983948130584`,0.49514685900067146`},{0.5601001838096595`,0.4952291466547238`},{0.5701019728062606`,0.4952990199882136`},{0.5801037618028617`,0.4954981261098205`},{0.5901055507994627`,0.49581927136967574`},{0.6001073397960638`,0.4961027882281859`},{0.6101091287926649`,0.4963622147030731`},{0.6201109177892659`,0.4966042118151429`},{0.630112706785867`,0.49683858164676903`},{0.640114495782468`,0.49705190249915443`},{0.6501162847790691`,0.49712592063118116`},{0.6601180737756702`,0.49718413826216856`},{0.6701198627722712`,0.4972295004992033`},{0.6801216517688723`,0.4972077101740653`},{0.6901234407654734`,0.4970539255431156`}};
```

Comment: Please put semicolons at the ends of such long data lists.  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for the very useful help you gave me. You helped me to rethink the problem. I finally understood that I had to interpolate separately the x and y components of the curves.

Comment: Ok Michael, sorry, I will put semicolons. I am really new to posting on this site.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You've already done the hard work in putting the path together.  Now you could just do a quick and dirty interpolation and `FindRoot`.

```
rex = Interpolation[Thread[{Range@Length@pathre, First /@ pathre}]];
rey = Interpolation[Thread[{Range@Length@pathre, Last /@ pathre}]];
imx = Interpolation[Thread[{Range@Length@pathim, First /@ pathim}]];
imy = Interpolation[Thread[{Range@Length@pathim, Last /@ pathim}]];

{rex[t], rey[t]} /. FindRoot[{rex[t] - imx[s], rey[t] - imy[s]}, {{s, 1}, {t, 1}}]
```

> `{0.436125,0.512288}`

[image: 1]

Comment: Thank you, it seems to work fine, I have to process about 300 of this kind of plots, so I hope it works fine with all of them. By the way, with your method I arrived to a different result: {0.449139, 0.50672}(seems correct anyway), and this error: InterpolatingFunction::dmval: "Input value {-244.665} lies outside the range of data in the interpolating function. Extrapolation will be used. "

Answer (score 7):

Perhaps this is close enough?

```
Graphics`Mesh`FindIntersections[{Line@re, Line@im}]
(*  {{0.436215, 0.512333}}  *)
```

Comment: Hi Michael, maybe my question is very basic, but I could not make your code work on my version 9 of Mathematica

Answer (score 5):

A few of your points in the `im` list seemed to be wrong. I couldn't fully reproduce your plot. After removing those I did:

```
pathreInt1 = Interpolation[pathre[[All, 1]]];
pathreInt2 = Interpolation[pathre[[All, 2]]];
pathimInt1 = Interpolation[pathim[[All, 1]]];
pathimInt2 = Interpolation[pathim[[All, 2]]];

pathreInt1["Domain"]
(* {{1., 51.}} *)

pathimInt1["Domain"]
(* {{1., 119.}} *)

sol = 
 NMinimize[{(pathreInt1[t1] - pathimInt1[t2])^2 + (pathreInt2[t1] - 
       pathimInt2[t2])^2, 1 <= t1 <= 51, 1 <= t2 <= 119}, {t1, t2}, 
  MaxIterations -> 1000]
(* {2.013*10^-17, {t1 -> 26.3953, t2 -> 34.3709}} *)

Graphics[Line@{pathre, pathim}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
 Frame -> True, 
 Epilog -> {Red, Point[{pathreInt1[t1], pathreInt2[t1]} /. sol[[2]]]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

By the way: you didn't tell this, but your code is intended to order your points such that neighboring points are next to each other in the list in order to prevent this from happening:

```
Graphics[Line@{re, im}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

However, there is already a built-in function that does this: `ListCurvePathPlot`.

```
Show[ListCurvePathPlot[re], ListCurvePathPlot[im], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: After getting the output from `ListCurvePathPlot[]`, you can then use Michael's method…

Comment: Hi, I tried all the options in the thread I referenced http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/47332/parametric-interpolation-of-2d-data, and found the one that gave me the best results. Try to apply the method you mention to the set of data on that thread, and you will look that it fails.

Comment: You are right, some points were wrong, it was an issue while pasting the data, now I corrected it. Thanks for the observation, and for your long response.

Answer (score 2):

### BSplineFunction + NArgMin

```
{f1, f2} = BSplineFunction /@ {pathre, pathim};
τ = Last @ Quiet @ NArgMin[{Norm[f1[t] - f2[α t]], 0 <= t <= 1, 0 <= α < 1}, {α, t}]
```

> 0.4763124688614422

```
ParametricPlot[{f1@t, f2@t}, {t, 0, 1},  Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[.03], Point @ f1 @ τ}]
```

[image]