# Interpolation showing noise in "non-noisy" data set

Tags: interpolation

Stuck trying to get the interpolating function to match the (what I thought was a) smooth point set, how best to deal with this?  Many thanks.

```
pts={{-1.01605*10^-6, -19.2734}, {-0.572436, -19.0369}, {-1.13153, 
-18.7846}, {-1.67697, -18.5171}, {-2.20845, -18.2351}, {-2.72569, 
-17.9392}, {-3.22846, -17.6302}, {-3.7165, -17.3086}, {-4.18962, 
-16.9752}, {-4.64762, -16.6306}, {-5.09034, -16.2755}, {-5.51762, 
-15.9105}, {-5.92934, -15.5362}, {-6.3254, -15.1533}, {-6.70569, 
-14.7625}, {-7.07016, -14.3644}, {-7.41876, -13.9595}, {-7.75144, 
-13.5486}, {-8.06821, -13.1321}, {-8.36906, -12.7108}, {-8.65402, 
-12.2853}, {-8.92312, -11.856}, {-9.17643, -11.4236}, {-9.41401, 
-10.9886}, {-9.63595, -10.5516}, {-9.84235, -10.1131}, {-10.0333, 
-9.6737}, {-10.209, -9.23385}, {-10.3696, -8.79409}, {-10.5152, 
-8.3549}, {-10.6459, -7.91677}, {-10.7621, -7.48016}, {-10.8638, 
-7.04554}, {-10.9513, -6.61334}, {-11.0248, -6.184}, {-11.0845, 
-5.75792}, {-11.1307, -5.33552}, {-11.1637, -4.91719}, {-11.1835, 
-4.50329}, {-11.1907, -4.09419}, {-11.1854, -3.69024}, {-11.1678, 
-3.29176}, {-11.1384, -2.89909}, {-11.0973, -2.51251}, {-11.045, 
-2.13233}, {-10.9816, -1.75882}, {-10.9076, -1.39224}, {-10.8232, 
-1.03284}, {-10.7287, -0.680859}, {-10.6246, -0.336509}, {-10.511, 0}}

fn = Interpolation[pts];

Show[
 ListLinePlot[pts, PlotStyle -> Red],
 Plot[fn[x], {x, -11., 0.}, PlotStyle -> Dashed]]
```

[image]

Comment: Your points are not in fact a function. You have two $y$ values corresponding to some values of $x$. That is the reason of the errors. See [this post](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/47332/parametric-interpolation-of-2d-data)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
fx = Interpolation[pts[[All, 1]]];
fy = Interpolation[pts[[All, 2]]];
ParametricPlot[{fx[t], fy[t]}, {t, 1, Length[pts]}, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio]
```

plot
[image]

Answer (score 6):

A short one:

```
fn = Interpolation /@ Transpose@pts;
ParametricPlot[Through@fn@x, {x, 1, Length@pts}]
```

The following is another way. I think it's poorly documented (or not at all).Note that the function interpoltion returns a list from a scalar.

```
fn = Interpolation[Transpose[{Range@Length@pts, pts}]];
ParametricPlot[fn@x, {x, 1, Length@pts}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Nicely compact. ;-)