# How to take dot product of every element in a list?

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list of coordinates (coord):

```
{{59.1915, 42.0843}, {62.0695, 71.2996}, {48.4124, 52.1423}, 
 {51.3325,60.8624}, {54.8544, 44.72}, {55.39, 63.9032},
 {59.1566,67.2319}, {48.1271, 57.0733}, {63.0908, 76.0996}, 
 {50.644, 47.5917}}
```

Using:

```
diffcoord = Differences[coord]
```

I can calculate the difference between consecutive coordinates:

```
{{2.87796, 29.2153}, {-13.6571, -19.1573}, {2.9201, 8.7201}, 
 {3.52192, -16.1424}, {0.53561, 19.1832}, {3.76663, 3.32865}, 
 {-11.0295, -10.1585}, {14.9637, 19.0262}, {-12.4468, -28.5079}}
```

Now, I want to calculate:

```
d = dx1*dx2 + dy1*dy2
```

for each pair of differenced coordinate in the list.
where $dx_1 = x_2-x_1, dy_1=y_2-y_1$ (which is the first element of the diffcoord list)

I was trying to use `Dot`but I found out that it's not going to do I want. Is there a command like `Differences` or `Accumulate` that does what I need.

**More info:**

I am trying to calculate the correlation between unit tangent vectors ([uni-leipzig.de/~pwm/web/?section=introduction&page=polymers](http://uni-leipzig.de/~pwm/web/?section=introduction&page=polymers)). To calculate unit tangent vector, I need to take the derivative of the curve at that point. Since it's cubic spline, I can't do so. I am trying to approximate it by ([iiserpune.ac.in/~cathale/lects/bio322-phybio1/2013bio322/…](http://www.iiserpune.ac.in/~cathale/lects/bio322-phybio1/2013bio322/lab2-mtPersistLen.pdf)) . Do you know of any better way to do it?

This question is a follow-up to this question:
[How to find a length of a curve constructed using Spline?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/83181/how-to-find-a-length-of-a-curve-constructed-using-spline/83183?noredirect=1#comment225688_83183)

Comment: Wait… did you want to take the dot product for the original list, or for the differenced one? In any event: `Dot @@@ Partition[(* coordinates *), 2, 1]`.

Comment: Differenced ones. I Just added more info to get my point across.

Comment: "Since it's cubic spline, I can't do so." - well, actually, you can. Here is a sketch: the routines I gave [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/11738) for generating cubic B-splines ought to also work in 3D; having generated the parameter values and control points, you can then explicitly generate the component functions with a procedure similar to the one in [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/24462) to generate the unit tangent vector.

Answer (score 4):

Here's how I'd do it. Starting with diffcoord

```
diffcoord = {{2.87796, 29.2153}, {-13.6571, -19.1573}, {2.9201, 
  8.7201}, {3.52192, -16.1424}, {0.53561, 19.1832}, {3.76663, 
  3.32865}, {-11.0295, -10.1585}, {14.9637, 
  19.0262}, {-12.4468, -28.5079}};
```

Pair each element with the next and Dot the pairs.

```
Dot@@@(Transpose@{diffcoord[[1;;-2]],diffcoord[[2;;-1]]})
```

The output is

```
{-598.991, -206.934, -130.479, -307.777, 65.8716, -75.3581, -358.32,
-728.647}
```

There is certainly a more clever way to combine the two if you need to do this on huge lists, but this makes sense to me.

Edit: @Guess who it is reminded me that `Partition` has a 3rd argument to specify an offset, which makes this a lot nicer looking!

```
Dot@@@Partition[diffcoord,2,1]
```

Comment: Would've used `Partition[]` myself… :)

Comment: I am so new to Mathematica. I don't know much about it's power. @Guesswhoitis. your suggestion worked. However, I do not understand what `Dot@@@` is doing. I am currently in the process of reading : http://www.mathprogramming-intro.org/download/MathProgrammingIntro.pdf .. I think I will  get to `Map` in 3-4 days.

Comment: @psimeson, a tip: everytime you encounter an unfamiliar function or operator, highlight it on the front end and press F1. In this case, you should be seeing the entry for `Apply[]`…

Answer (score 3):

[image]

```
lst = {{59.1915, 42.0843}, {62.0695, 71.2996}, {48.4124, 
    52.1423}, {51.3325, 60.8624}, {54.8544, 44.72}, {55.39, 
    63.9032}, {59.1566, 67.2319}, {48.1271, 57.0733}, {63.0908, 
    76.0996}, {50.644, 47.5917}};

BlockMap[Apply[Dot], Differences@lst, 2, 1]
```

> {-598.991, -206.934, -130.479, -307.777, 65.8725, -75.3586, -358.323,
>
> -728.65}

As of `v10.2` `PartitionMap` has been [superseded](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/Developer/ref/PartitionMap.html) by `BlockMap`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`PartitionMap`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/Developer/ref/PartitionMap.html) from Developer package, e.g.

```
lst = {{59.1915, 42.0843}, {62.0695, 71.2996}, {48.4124, 
    52.1423}, {51.3325, 60.8624}, {54.8544, 44.72}, {55.39, 
    63.9032}, {59.1566, 67.2319}, {48.1271, 57.0733}, {63.0908, 
    76.0996}, {50.644, 47.5917}};
Developer`PartitionMap[Dot @@ # &, Differences@lst, 2, 1]
```

yields:

```
{-598.991, -206.934, -130.479, -307.777, 65.8725, -75.3586, -358.323, \
-728.65}
```

A recent answer by Mr. Wizard brought this to my attention. I post in case others not aware.

Answer (score 0):

Your wording is very ambiguous.  You start with coordinates, then calculate the differences between successive points, and *then* claim you want to calculate dx1*dx2 + dxy*dy2 for each pair of coordinate [sic] in the list.  Do you mean for each *successive* pair of two-element lists?  Or the outer product, i.e., the differences between the each two-element list and *every other* two element list?

Please be clear.

You *might* mean you want the below (but I'm not sure):

```
Norm[#]^2 & /@ 
 Differences[{{2.87796, 29.2153}, {-13.6571, -19.1573}, {2.9201, 
    8.7201}, {3.52192, -16.1424}, {0.53561, 19.1832}, {3.76663, 
    3.32865}, {-11.0295, -10.1585}, {14.9637, 
    19.0262}, {-12.4468, -28.5079}}]
```

Comment: I edited my question. Thanks for pointing out. English is not my first language so I can't express myself clearly.