# Why don't optimization functions like FindMinimum work with functions like BSplineFunction?

Tags: functions, mathematical-optimization, splines

Take a simple `BSplineFunction` and evaluate it at 0.25.

```
pts = {{1, 1}, {2, 3}, {3, -1}, {4, 1}, {5, 0}};
f = BSplineFunction[pts];
f[0.25]
```

and you get:

```
{2.1875, 1.6875}
```

Now try the reverse: find a value for the parameter whose result is closest to the line x==2.1875?

```
FindMinimum[(f[t][[1]]-2.1875)^2,t]
```

and you get:

```
{0., {t -> 2.1875}}
```

The minimum may be correct, but the parameter value is wrong. Plotting the expression clearly shows a minimum at 0.25.

```
Plot[(f[t][[1]] - 2.1875)^2, {t,0,1}]
```

[image: Plot of the square of the difference of the first part of the B-spline function at t and 2.1875 as t goes from 0 to 1. A parabolic-looking function with a clear minimum at 0.25]

Comment: `BSplineFunction[]` does not do well when all you need is one component for optimization or root-finding. If need be, you can reconstruct the expression in terms of `BSplineBasis[]`, as was done [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/24462).

Comment: `f[t][[1]]` evaluates to `t`, so the `FindMinimum` expression in the question really is `FindMinimum[(t - 2.1875)^2, t]`, which is satisfied by `{0., {t -> 2.1875}}`.

Comment: See specifically: [(26037)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/26037/121).  Also related: [(14645)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/14645/121), [(21662)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/21662/121)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Define

```
g[t_?NumericQ] := BSplineFunction[pts][t][[1]]
```

Then,

```
Minimize[(g[t] - 2.1875)^2, t]
(* {0., {t -> 0.25}} *)
```

which is the desired result. (`NMinimize[(g[t] - 2.1875)^2, t]` and `FindMinimum[{(g[t] - 2.1875)^2, 0 <= t <= 1}, t] // Chop` also give the desired result.)

Why this works while

```
FindMinimum[(f[t][[1]] - 2.1875)^2, t]
(* {0., {t -> 2.1875}} *)
```

does not can be seen from the `FindMinimum` documentation (Details and Options section):

> FindMinimum first localizes the values of all variables, then evaluates f with the variables being symbolic, and then repeatedly evaluates the result numerically.

In other words, `FindMinimum` first converts `(f[t][[1]] - 2.1875)^2` to `(t - 2.1875)^2` and then minimizes the latter expression.  The function `g` prevents this from happening by blocking symbolic evaluation.

Incidentally, `Plot` does not first do symbolic evaluation and so does not create this problem.  Forcing it to perform symbolic evaluation first yields a curve different from that in the question.

```
Plot[Evaluate[(f[t][[1]] - 2.1875)^2], {t, 0, 3}]
```

[image]

which does have a minimum at `t == 2.1875`, as expected.